# If ip sets the network configuration, what program runs the configuration?

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface

the [linux foundation's page on iproute2](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/iproute2) says that the ip command "controls the ipv4 and ipv6 configuration", but I'm unclear of what actually runs instructions based on that configuration. What program does the work of creating the interfaces and connecting to the access points?

I think that that depends on the distribution. I think that NetworkManager does this job in redhat. But in alpine linux I've not found a networking program besides ip.

I think my question is, does it ONLY deal with configuration, and some other program does the work of connecting. Or can ip connect to access points all on its own?

Comment: the ip tutorial in here: <http://www.policyrouting.org/iproute2.doc.html> says that its used "for manipulating the Linux 2.2-2.6 network interface code". This implies that its the kernel that does the networking... But I'd need more detail into how the kernel does this, and how ip figures into that, for an answer.

Comment: the `ip` program issues the commands to the kernel to configure the networking. It is typically used from the command line to tweak the configuration or from startup scripts for static configurations. Programs like `NetworkManager` and `netplan` attempt to present a higher level view, like "If I am connected to my home WiFi then set up this configuration, else if I am plugged into the corporate LAN at work then use this configuration, else if I am somewhere else (e.g. hotel or coffeeshop) then use this configuration". Both the high and low level tools have their uses.

Comment: As far as connection to access points, typically a program called wpasupplicant is used to establish the wifi link.

Comment: So its the kernel the one that executes on the configuration. And NetworkManager adds to the configuration ability without executing on the connection itself?